# Оператор switch, нужен ли break после метки default?

Tags: c++, switch

Какой смысл в операторе `break` после метки `default`, если оператор `switch` после `default` итак завершает свою работу?

Часто вижу примеры, как с `break` так и без после `default`:

```
switch(number)
{
  case 0: cout << "Too small.\n";  break;
  case 1: cout << "One.\n";  break;
  case 2: cout << "Two.\n"; break;       
  case 3: cout << "Three.\n"; break;
  default: cout << "Too large.\n"; 
  break; // какой смысл в этом break?
}
```

Comment: Потому что этот `default` можно написать где угодно, хоть перед первым `case`.

Comment: Никакого, брейк нужен, чтобы секции отделять друг от друга, все пишут по-разному, у кого-то в голове представляется сначала общее действие, а потом специфичные, поэтому он в начале дефолт пишет.

Comment: Есть хорошие привычки (типа мыть руки перед едой), которые можно в принципе и не исполнять. Однако в один прекрасный момент (при ваянии программы методом копи/пасты), выясняется, что не очень нужный break, поставленный по привычке следовать хорошим манерам, сохранил Вам уйму времени, избавив от необходимости ловить непонятно откуда возникшую ошибку.

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял друзья, то `break` актуален, только если `default` в `switch` указывается первым, то есть перед всеми кейсами.

Comment: @Michael, нет! default'a может вообще не быть, он может быть посередине. Это вообще неважно.

Comment: Кроме общих случаев, есть и тонкости - это естественно, в зависимости от того, что требуется получить в итоге. Так или иначе, я вас услышал и понял.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Синтаксически, нет необходимости в самом последнем `break`, причём неважно в какой секции он находится.

```
switch(number)
{
  case 1: cout << 1; break;
  case 2: cout << 2; break;       
  default:
  case 0: cout << "Мало"; break;
  case 3: cout << "Много"; /*break;*/
}
```

По сути, `break` - это goto на позицию сразу за фигурной скобкой. (*А `continue` на позицию перед ней, но только в циклах*)
В этом свете, очевидна излишнесть этого оператора.

---

Однако, этот `break` всё ещё может быть полезен, если список случаев (`case`) может изменяться в будущем.
При наличии всех `break` сложнее ошибиться и получить вот такую ошибку:

```
switch(number)
{
  case 1: cout << 1; break;
  case 2: cout << 2; break;       
  default:
  case 0: cout << "Мало"; break;
  case 3: cout << 3;         // При добавлении строчки, забыли добавить пропущенный break
  case 4: cout << "Много";
}
```

Это становится более актуальным, если секции не такие тривиальные, и просто окинув взглядом `switch` не сразу понятно, что к чему относится.

Comment: Вот `break` после `return` - действительно лишний, но на это сейчас любая IDE умеет ругаться.

Comment: **(А continue на позицию перед ней)**

а с каких пор continue работает в switch

Comment: @KoVadim, просто для общности написал. Уточнил.